# Wix optional feature package

Tags: wix, burn

We've used wix to create our installer for some time now, but previously we've relied on our customer installing SQL themselves.

I now want to include SQLLocalDB for our smaller customers as an option in our installer, but I don't know the correct way to implement this.

I've added radio buttons to our product to chose between using SQLLocalDB or an external server but how do I pass this variable to the bundle's InstallCondition for SQLLocalDB. I Tried using the registry in between but the registry is read as soon as the bundle msi is started and not after the first package has been installed.

My first idea when I started implementing this was to install SQLLocalDB, create the database and the tables from a custom action, but I've now realized that isn't possible

**So to finalize my questions:**

1. How do I add optional features correctly?
2. If I want to create the database and create/update the tables, do I have to create yet another msi for this and add it as a third package in the bundle?

Comment: Did you find a solution to create optional packages ?

Comment: I'm sorry no. I gave up on that solution.